# Oracle SQL Select Split Results

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, select, substr

I am trying to create a SQL statement to return only a portion of a column result.  I have looked into SubString and InString, but am having a lot of trouble returning the values I need.

Example table data is:

```
RM123 - N60
RM123 - J44
RM123 - Q24
RM123 - U55-R07 - 1
RM123 - U54-R06 - 1
RM123 - R47-R11 - 1
```

I need to only return the data after the second space and before the third (could contain dashes, will NOT contain spaces in the results needed):

```
N60
J44
Q24
U55-R07
U54-R06
R47-R11
```

Equivalent of what I need in awk...

```
$ awk '{print $3}' /tmp/sql.out
N60
J44
Q24
U55-R07
U54-R06
R47-R11
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The second space in the line overall, or just here (ie what about '__-_', where '_' is standing in for space)?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you are asking, but there should be no underscores in the column data.  Using spaces as a delimiter, I need the third column (between the second space third space).  I'm more or less lost, so I don't have much to share.  Here is all I have started with using information from other questions I see posted:  `select SUBSTR(Serial_Number, 1, INSTR(Serial_Number, ' ')-1) AS ouput`.  This however only provides "RM123" in this case, I can't sort out how to get the position of the second space, and length of the data between which is what substr seems to require.

Comment: Does `INSTR()` allow you to specify a starting index (#hint#).  Also, you may have better luck wrapping things in some layers of CTEs, allowing you to only have to calculate function values once.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to my own question, so I'm posting it for others.  You can use regexp_substr to solve this.  Here an example:

```
select regexp_substr(columnname,'[^ ]+', 1, 3)
```

This will return the third column using spaces as delimiters.  All props goes to this page which gave me the hint:

http://andrewfraserdba.com/2011/07/13/split-space-delimited-string-with-regexp-sql/